# Is the SwiftUI Path object's string format a standard?

Tags: swift, vector, swiftui

I am exporting SwiftUI [Path](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path) objects to strings using the [description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/description) property, for storage in a database.

This is an example of the format that it produces:

```
0 0 m 1 0 l 1 2 l 0.25 2 l 0.25 0.25 l 0 0.25 l h
```

This can be used later to initialise a new Path object, recreating the path.

I'm not overly familiar with vector paths - is this a well defined format, perhaps a standard? Or is this something that is specific to SwiftUI?

I can't see a format mentioned in the linked documentation.

I ask as at some point I intend these formats to be cross platform, and would like to future proof it now by choosing a more agnostic format if necessary.

Comment: M probably means move, L is line, H might be close

Comment: That looks like the path construction operators as used in PDF: m = moveto, l = lineto, h = closepath. Compare with "8.5.2 Path Construction Operators" in https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: Thanks, yeah it does look like it sort of follows that. But then looking at some other operations you can add quad curves which are signified by a "q" operator, which I don't see in the PDF spec.

Comment: I see, so it is probably similar to (or inspired by) the PDF operators. So you would have to reverse engineer it, and that might break in the future. – A better option might be to enumerate its `cgPath` using the `applyWithBlock` method, which *is* documented.